# Parsing a MovieClip for children?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

How can I reliably iterate through a MovieClip for every child?

I'm working on a game and a great way to lay out my levels is inside a MovieClip, with each frame being a new level.  The problem is that when I move on to frame 2 or 3 and try to iterate through the MovieClip's children, I'm getting a different number (less) than is actually on that frame.

I think it's because the instances from the previous frame are being carried over to the new frame.

A simple solution is to create a new MovieClip for every level instead of a new frame inside each MovieClip, but this isn't the most scalable solution (say I want to remove a level or add a level between other levels, etc).

Any ideas?

Comment: given any thought to using sprites?  it doesn't sound like you're using the timeline of the movie clip, and sprites substantially less overhead

Comment: But that's not the problem there... Still - good thing it is.

Comment: @Aurel300, that's why its in the comments, not the answers. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Tried at home, works :

```
var mc : $TestMovie2 = new $TestMovie2();
addChild(mc);
mc.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, function(e : Event) : void {
    trace("add to mc :",e.target,e.target["name"]);
});
mc.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, function(e : Event) : void {
    trace("remove from mc :",e.target,e.target["name"]);
});         
mc.stop();
mc.gotoAndStop(2);
trace("frame 2 numChildren: ",mc.numChildren);
var i : int = mc.numChildren;
while (i--) {
    trace(mc.getChildAt(i).name);
}
mc.gotoAndStop(3);
trace("frame 3 numChildren: ",mc.numChildren);
i = mc.numChildren;
while (i--) {
    trace(mc.getChildAt(i).name);
}

// output :
// add to mc : [object $TestMovie3] $child_1_frame2
// add to mc : [object $TestMovie3] $child_3_frame2
// add to mc : [object $TestMovie3] $child_2_frame2
// frame 2 numChildren:  3
// $child_2_frame2
// $child_3_frame2
// $child_1_frame2
// remove from mc : [object $TestMovie3] $child_1_frame2
// remove from mc : [object $TestMovie3] $child_3_frame2
// remove from mc : [object $TestMovie3] $child_2_frame2
// add to mc : [object $TestMovie3] $child_1_frame3
// add to mc : [object $TestMovie3] $child_2_frame3
// add to mc : [object $TestMovie3] $child_3_frame3
// add to mc : [object $TestMovie3] $child_4_frame3
// add to mc : [object $TestMovie3] $child_5_frame3
// frame 3 numChildren:  5
// $child_5_frame3
// $child_4_frame3
// $child_3_frame3
// $child_2_frame3
// $child_1_frame3
```

**$TestMovie2** is a MovieClip in the flash IDE library containing :
frame 1 : NOTHING
frame 2 : 3 **$TestMovie3** MovieClip
frame 3 : 5 **$TestMovie3** MovieClip

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all the children for the current frame and then remove them, and then go to the next frame.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Document class, alongside specific classes for your game. Just use the fla for your graphic assets.

This way, you will not be frame dependent and you would have total control over your MovieClips instances for each level.